# TFileStream.WriteBuffer XE4 VS XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe4

This code is running on Delphi XE4 perfectly well:

```
var
b: byte;
fl: TFileStream;
filename:string;
begin
b:= $2F;
filename:='C:\test.exe';
fl:= tFileStream.Create(filename, 0,fmOpenReadWrite);
fl.Position:= $C;
fl.WriteBuffer(b,sizeof(b));
fl.free
end;
```

However, when I run exactly the same code on Delphi XE7 on the same PC, it fails with the error "Stream write error".

Comment: `Fl:=TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmOpenReadWrite);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `TFileStream` constructor, you are setting the `Mode` parameter to 0 (`fmOpenRead`) and the `Rights` parameter to `fmOpenReadWrite`.  You need to swap them:

```
//fl:= tFileStream.Create(filename, 0, fmOpenReadWrite);
fl:= tFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenReadWrite, 0);
```

Or simply:

```
fl:= tFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenReadWrite);
```

When the `fmCreate` flag is not present in the `Mode` parameter, `TFileStream` calls `FileOpen()` instead of `FileCreate()`.

In XE4, the `Mode` and `Rights` parameters are `OR`'ed together when `TFileStream` calls `FileOpen()` on Windows:

```
inherited Create(FileOpen(AFileName, Mode or Rights));
// which is: FileOpen(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmOpenReadWrite)
// effectively: FileOpen(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite)
```

That is why your code works in XE4.  You are opening the file in a read/write mode.

In XE7, the `Rights` parameter is ignored when `TFileStream` calls `FileOpen()` on *every* platform:

```
inherited Create(FileOpen(AFileName, Mode));
// effectively: FileOpen(AFileName, fmOpenRead)
```

That is why your code does not work in XE7.  You are opening the file in a read-only mode.